# How to measure the biomass of hydroponic plants in netpot/rockwool DWC system?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, experimental-design

I'm doing an experiment with 4 kale plants, each in their own small deep water culture (DWC) system. Each plant was transplanted in rockwool with netpots and clay pebbles. But I need to periodically and accurately measure the biomass of each plant. The roots have grown through the rockwool and netpots and I don't want to rip out the roots.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you did enough replications in your experiment, you could harvest one or more plants and measure fresh weight, and then gently oven dry for about 48 hours at like 160 degrees F and then take a dry weight as a measure of biomass. I don't know a non-destructive way to do it. A lesser alternative would be to measure plant height and number of leaves, though this would be less accurate. There are devices that measure leaf area, and I know a simple, low-tech way to measure leaf area.

Comment: we appreciate references to all answers to allow all users a chance to try and understand the answer and go for more information - you might want to add some references as this would strengthen your response